# "If I were born in 1920s, my name would have been Margaret"

Tags: conditionals

Yesterday I heard someone saying

> If I were born in 1920s, my name would have been Margaret.

and I was confused why she didn't say

> If i had been born in 1920s

What's the difference here?

Comment: It seems like hypercorrection to me. She was trying to use the subjunctive mood, and so used *were* incorrectly. It should be *had been*, or, to keep using *were*, *were* ***to have been*** … *my name* ***would be***..

Comment: A native English speaker would say "If I were (or had been) born in **the** 1920s".

Comment: Where did you hear this? I sounds like an English regional dialect to me,  possibly East Midlands or some parts of Yorkshire.

Comment: I'm upvoting this question because of the dozens of similar questions at Quora, Word Reference, etc., none of which have a clear, correct answer. This is evidently a very common stumbling block. It may have reached the point where we just have to accept it as informal.

Comment: I agree with BoldBen - this sounds like dialect in which *in **the** 1920s* is reduced to *in **t'** 1920s* and finally to *in **1920s***.

Comment: @Bold Ben "If ah wer born in't nahnteen twenties, ..."

Answer (score -2):

A subjunctive form of the verb is used when talking about hypothetical scenarios.

When you’re describing a wish or an impossible situation, use were instead of was.

Comment: That's true, but not the answer. We use _were_ for hypotheticals in the present/future. For hypotheticals in the past we use _had been_.